# Suspend doesn't act properly

Tags: 16.04, suspend, intel

So hello there. I've been using Ubuntu for a long time. In my latest laptop while using Windows I could make the computer go to sleep properly. However in Ubuntu each time I suspend it, it shuts down suddenly upon waking up from sleep. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and my laptop has intel sandybridge graphics. I found several related issues regarding this situation but I couldn't find any solution. And I must add that this has happened to me with every Ubuntu version I've used. Any ideas how to solve it, since not being able to suspend my laptop is a huge draw back since I'm using it mostly on the campus.

The output of `free -h`:

> total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available Memory:        1,7G        733M        265M        114M        789M        704M
>   Swap:         1,9G        651M        1,2G
>   Blockquote

Comment: Please run `free -h` and post it